# How to interpret this Einstein notation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, notation

Context: Deriving the Euler equation for fluid flow

The author of the [article](http://www.av8n.com/physics/euler-flow.htm) that I am reading says

> We now consider the effect of pressure. It contributes a force on the particles in the control volume, namely $$F_i += \int Pd_iS = - \int \nabla_iPdV$$ A uniform gravitational field contributes another force, namely $$F_i += \int \rho g_i dV$$

The author may have made a typo where "+=" should just be "=". Sorry for any confusion.

**Question**: How would you write either of the above equations without Einstein Notation? Particularly, I am having trouble understanding $Pd_iS$ and $\nabla_iPdV$. Also, does $+=$ have any significance, or is it probably a typo?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with Einstein notation in your formulae.

Comment: Maybe this isn't actually Einstein notation but simply using indices to shorten the formulas. I'm just not sure how to expand the shorthand index notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your source article:

> We can go through the same process for momentum instead of mass. We use Π to represent momentum, to avoid conflict with P which represents pressure. The total momentum in the control volume is:
>   $$ \Pi_i = \int \rho \nu_i dV $$
>   where the index i runs over the three components of the momentum.

I assume this notational convention is held throughout the article. Therefore, you can rewrite your equation as three equations, namely:
$$ F_x = - \int \nabla_x P dV \\
F_y = - \int \nabla_y P dV \\
F_z = - \int \nabla_z P dV
$$

This is not Einstein notation, it should be noted. Einstein notation is the convention that indices that are repeated as both a subscript and a superscript are implicitly summed over, i.e. $\Lambda^{\mu}v_\mu = \Lambda^{0}v_0 + \Lambda^{1}v_1 + \dots + \Lambda^{n}v_n $.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What does the notation $\nabla_x$ mean? I know what the gradient is for a function but don't understand what the subscript indicates.

Comment: In this context it likely means the x-component of the gradient.